# Chrome Three Dot Menu Disappeared

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I no longer see the chrome three dot menu.  I'm including a screen shot (Hopefully I don't just need new glasses :) ):
[image]

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched the internet for *google chrome three dots missing* and found a possible reason for the three dots (**⋮**) being AWOL:

For some reason (see the link below), it may have morphed into the yellow round icon (with an upward-pointing white arrow) at the right-end of your address bar. Hover on that, you may even see a tooltip indicating that updates are available.

The following image is from  [Three Dots in Chrome](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/a13mhi/three_dots_in_chrome/eamlze7?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

[image: Morphed icon]

More reading:

- [How do I reinstate the Menu (3 vertical dots)? …](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/how-do-i-reinstate-the-menu-3-vertical-dots-its-gone-and-google-chrome-beta-didnt-include-them.197619/)